Serializing table data with reference entity with NewtonSoft.Json in ASP.NET 4.8 Web API
I am working on an ASP.NET Web API which returns table data from database using linq2SQL.
I need to include reference entity data to response, till only one level.
If reference table next referencing another table... then don't want to include it.
Tables in linq2Sql.dbml files are like...
class user
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

class Department 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable GetTableDataWithFilters(string tableName, DataFilter filters, out long totalRows, out bool isFiltersApplied)
{
    var type = DbContext.GetTypeExtension(tableName) ?? throw new TableNotSupportedException();
    isFiltersApplied = false;

    ITable table = DbContext.GetTable(type);
    var result = table.AsQueryable();

    if (filters != null && filters.Filters.Count > 0)
    {
        var lambdaExpression = table.GetLambdaExpressionForFilters(type, filters.Filters);

        if (lambdaExpression != null)
        {
            result = result.Where(lambdaExpression);
            isFiltersApplied = true;
        }
    }

    totalRows = result.Count();

    if (filters != null)
        result = result.ApplyPagination(filters.PageNo, filters.PageSize);

    return result;
}

In Global.aspx...
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
     .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
     .PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
     .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

I have confirmed, result variable after executing query actually contains reference entity data. But after serialization, client/caller are not getting the department entity.
Output:
[
    {
         "Id": 1,
         "Name": "Testuser",
         "DepartmentId": 7,
    },
    {
         "Id": 2,
         "Name": "Testuser123",
         "DepartmentId": 5,
    }
]


Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling - make it none, and include Department
User.Include("Department")   or var students = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId)
.Join(_context.Department, u => u.DepartmentID, d => d.id, (u, d) => d)
.ToList();
